# Merging tables with PHP similar_text and UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables in MySQL I'd like to merge:

```
table_1
--------------------------------------------------------
id |     table_1_name           |   table_1_art
--------------------------------------------------------
1  |     Ernest Hemingway       |   Writer
--------------------------------------------------------
2  |     Mark Twain             |   Writer
--------------------------------------------------------
3  |     Jackson Pollock        |   Painter
--------------------------------------------------------
4  |     Miles Davis            |   Musician
--------------------------------------------------------
5  |     Akira Kurosawa         |   Cinema
--------------------------------------------------------


table_2
--------------------------------------------------------
id |     table_2_name             |   table_2_art
--------------------------------------------------------
1  |     Hemingway, ernest        |   Writer
--------------------------------------------------------
2  |     Twain, Mark              |   Writer
--------------------------------------------------------
3  |     P., Jackson              |   Painter
--------------------------------------------------------
4  |     Miles Dewey Davis        |   Musician
--------------------------------------------------------
5  |     Bukowski, Charles        |   Poetry
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to update the field table_2_name with the data of table_1_name, but only if there is a similarity between them. I am using similar_text, and selecting similarities over 40%:

```
<?php

// Connection
$server = "****";
$user = "****";
$pass = "****";
$db_name = "****";
$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db_name);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    echo "Connected <br/>";
}

//Begin
$petition = "SELECT * FROM table_1,  table_2";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $petition);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $table_1_name = $row['table_1_name'];
    $table_1_art = $row['table_1_art'];
    $table_2_name = $row['table_2_name'];
    $table_2_art =$row['table_2_art'];

//Ask for similarities
similar_text($table_1_name, $table_2_name, $percent);

//Show coincidences over 40%
if ($percent > "40%") {
    echo $table_1_name." — ".$table_2_name." — ".$percent."% <br />";

//Update field in table_2_name for this coincidences
$sql = "UPDATE table_2 SET table_2_name = '$table_1_name'";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {
        echo "updated <br/> <br/>";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: " . $conn->error." <br/> <br/>";
    }
}
    $conn->close();
}
```

But I can't get results. Instead of this:

```
table_2
--------------------------------------------------------
id |     table_2_name             |   table_2_art
--------------------------------------------------------
1  |     Ernest Hemingway         |   Writer
--------------------------------------------------------
2  |     Mark Twain               |   Writer
--------------------------------------------------------
3  |     Jackson Pollock          |   Painter
--------------------------------------------------------
4  |     Miles Davis              |   Musician
--------------------------------------------------------
5  |     Bukowski, Charles        |   Poetry
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I get this:

```
table_2
--------------------------------------------------------
id |     table_2_name             |   table_2_art
--------------------------------------------------------
1  |     Ernest Hemingway         |   Writer
--------------------------------------------------------
2  |     Ernest Hemingway         |   Writer
--------------------------------------------------------
3  |     Ernest Hemingway         |   Painter
--------------------------------------------------------
4  |     Ernest Hemingway         |   Musician
--------------------------------------------------------
5  |     Ernest Hemingway         |   Poetry
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm sure it is a very common mistake, at least for beginners, but I can't find it!

Nikita

PD: as @denny said, the sql needs a condition, and I forgot to say that I tried some options, like:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table_2 SET table_2_name = '$table_1_name' WHERE ($percent > '45%')";
```

The problem is now there: which condition and how. Can't believe is that difficult…

Comment: Why 2 tables with very similar data?

Comment: Its an example. I have two tables with some thousand records each, but I could't post them here… ;)

Comment: It would be very hard to do.Since you dont have a foreign key, you need to create one on the name columns,and manipulate one column to match the other(since the name and surname are reversed) Slow and painful,then you can use `FROM t1.join t2 WHERE t1.name=t2.name` in your update.

Answer (score 0):

Change sql

`$sql = "UPDATE table_2 SET table_2_name = '$table_1_name'";`

To this

`$sql = "UPDATE table_2 SET table_2_name = '$table_1_name'" where column="your condition";`

Syntax:-

`update table_name set column_name = 'value' where column_name ='your_condition'`

If you excute

`update table_name set column_name = 'value'`

It will update whole table row

Comment: Hm, of course… Without the condition it will update all the records of this column. I forgot to say that I tried some approaches for the condition, but I can't find the way.

How can I create a condition with the records that match the similarity? Something like this:

$sql = "UPDATE table_2 SET table_2_name = '$table_1_name' WHERE $percent > '40%'';

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way.

First of all, I was making a mistake: I was closing the connection in the middle of the `while`:

```
$conn->close();
}
```

And should be and the very end:

```
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Also, I discovered that is much better to export de data to a third table with `INSET INTO` than trying to `UPDATE` the first table.

First I compare cells:

```
$similar_text($table_1_name, $table_2_name, $percent);
```

And then export the results to table_3, adding a field for the percentage:

```
if ($percent_autor > "40%") {
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_3 (table_3_name, table_3_art, percent)
VALUES ('$table_1_name', '$table_1_art, '$percent')";   
}
```

And that's all. At the end there will be some rows with repeated data, but is easy to find and delete them ;)